# Pegar o nome do site na url em javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url

Galera, tenho o seguinte:
Posso ter as seguintes situações de uma url: www.exemplo.com.br ou http://exemplo.com.br ou http://www.exemplo.com.br e tambem com HTTPS. Gostaria de pegar somente a palavra "exemplo". Porem não sei por onde começar pois pode ter varias situações como estão vendo!
Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta usar:

```
window.location.hostname
```

Pode dar uma olhada no objeto Location, que ele tem vários atributes que pode ser interessante para a sua solução.

Caso a url esteja em uma variável, divide a url em um array como está na resposta do Miguel.

```
var url = "www.google.com.br"
url.split('.')
=> Array [ "www", "google", "com", "br" ]
url.split('.')[1]
=> google
```

Comment: COmo faço com a url em uma variavel? Exemplo: var url = "www.google.com.br"?

Comment: @Thiago atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Faz o seguinte, a partir do nome domínio (`window.location.hostname`):

```js
var url = window.location.hostname; // obter o dominio
var url_splt = url.split('.')
var url_name = url_splt[url_splt.length - 2];
alert(url_name);
```

Para o caso de `.... .com.br` deves fazer (em vez de `url_splt[url_splt.length - 2]`):

```
url_splt[url_splt.length - 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
var splt = window.location.hostname.split('.')
var dominio = (splt[0] === 'www') ? splt[1] : splt[0];
console.log(dominio);
```